# openssl fails to install from source ERROR: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl

Tags: linux, openssl, compile

I am trying to install openssl by source I run:

```
wget  wget ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2g
./config --prefix=/home/david/project shared 
make depend
make test
make install
make
```

It fails after make test is executed with:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/project/openssl-1.0.1s'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/david/project/openssl-1.0.1s/test'
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [link_app.gnu] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/david/project/openssl-1.0.1s/test'
make[1]: *** [bntest] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/david/project/openssl-1.0.1s/test'
make: *** [tests] Error 2
```

How can libssl-dev be installed from source since I am not using package manager ?

---

***EDIT***. I had:

```
[root@localhost lib64]# ls -l libssl*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 258456 Dec 15 19:46 libssl3.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Feb 27 22:10 libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 441240 Jan  8 14:45 libssl.so.1.0.1e
```

and added:

```
[root@localhost lib64]# ls -l libssl*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 258456 Dec 15 19:46 libssl3.so
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Mar 18 16:24 libssl.so -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     16 Feb 27 22:10 libssl.so.10 -> libssl.so.1.0.1e
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 441240 Jan  8 14:45 libssl.so.1.0.1e
```

How could I get round having to add the symbolic link ? Is there something I could do as an install option ?

Answer (score 0):

> ./config --prefix=/home/david/project shared

I don't normally use PREFIX. I would recommend using OPENSSLDIR since OpenSSL configure supports the option:

```
wget ftp://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
tar xvzf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz
cd openssl-1.0.2g
./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp --openssldir=/home/david/project 

make depend
make test
make install
```

---

Also, you seem to have an extra `make`. I'm guessing you probably don't need it. What purpose does it serve?

```
make depend
make test
make install
make
```

Also, you can probably avoid installing the man pages locally, and just use `make install_sw`:

```
make depend
make test
make install_sw
```

---

You should also consider using an RPATH to make sure you avoid runtime linking problems:

```
export MYPATH=/home/david/project 
./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp -Wl,-rpath=${MYPATH}/lib --openssldir=${MYPATH}
```

---

> EDIT. I had...

Before you begin installing into an existing installation directory, you should probably just delete the old local installation:

```
export MYPATH=/home/david/project
rm -rf ${MYPATH}

./config shared no-ssl2 no-ssl3 no-comp -Wl,-rpath=${MYPATH}/lib --openssldir=${MYPATH}
make
make test
make install_sw
```

---

Also see [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki. It discusses PREFIX, OPENSSLDIR and RPATHs. It also discusses other configuration options, like `no-ssl2`, `no-ssl3` and `no-comp`.